# Indecomposable modules over a noncommutative noetherian ring

Tags: homological-algebra

Let $R$ be a noncommutative noetherian ring.
Can I say that every indecomposable injective right module appears as a direct summand of a term in the minimal injective resolution of $R_R$?
I know this is  true for a noetherian commutative ring.

Comment: Can you give a reference for the noetherian commutative case? I can't even see why it's true for $R=\mathbb Z$ at this moment.

Comment: See for example Theorem 1.1 put $R$ instead of $M$, in" Minimal injective resolutions with applications to dualizing modules and Gorenstein modules" a paper by for authors.

Comment: I’m sure that Zahra doesn’t expect a positive answer, as for Artin algebras this is the famous (and open) Generalized Nakayama Conjecture. But maybe a counterexample is known for noetherian rings.

Comment: Yes, Jeremy. You are right like always.